# Sum of a set with an equivalence class

Tags: functions, notation, quotient-spaces

I was studing and I can't understand the meaning of a notation. Let $\mathcal{F}(I)$ be the real algebra of functions $I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $I$ is a non-empty and finite set. We denote the space spaned by the unit $1 \in \mathcal{F}(I)$ as $\mathbb{R}$, it is,

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R} \cdot 1 := \{c\cdot1 \in \mathcal{F}(I):c \in \mathbb{R}\}
\end{equation}

I understood that $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of the constant functions. So, if I have a function with the domain $\mathcal{F}(I)/\mathbb{R}$, let's say $\rho$, what can the notation $\rho(f+\mathbb{R})$ mean?

Comment: My guess we would be that , with $\Omega=f+\mathbb{R}=\{f+c \in\mathcal{F}(I) : c\in \mathbb{R}\}$, it's the image of $\Omega$ under $\rho$, i.e. $\rho(\Omega)$, but I'm not entirely sure

Comment: I think this is it, because $f+\mathbb{R}$, according your notion, coincides with the equivalence class of $f$. Thank you so much.